# How to delete files in a Python Loop

Tags: python, automation, stata

I'm converting tif files to csv files. Here's my code. Note, the "copy" command is a Stata command, but you can just as easily download the zipfile from the link I provide in my code, likely with requests.

```
copy "https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/worldclim/v2.1/base/wc2.1_5m_prec.zip" ///
 "wc2.1_5m_prec.zip", replace

unzipfile wc2.1_5m_prec.zip, replace

erase readme.txt
```

python:

```
#Importing relevant commands

from osgeo import gdal
import pandas as pd, numpy as np, os, glob


#Loops over these to save space

for file in glob.glob("*.tif"):
    ds = gdal.Open(file)

    # TIFF to CSV 
    xyz = gdal.Translate(file+".xyz", ds)
    xyz = None

    df = pd.read_csv(file+".xyz", sep = " ", header = None)
    df.columns = ["x","y", "value"]
    df.to_csv(file+".csv", index = False)

    files_in_dir = glob.iglob('*.xyz')
    
    del df

    for _file in files_in_dir:
        print(_file) # just to be sure, you know how it is...
        os.remove(_file)
        
    os.remove(file)

end
```

I want to convert the first file (`wc2.1_5m_prec_01.tif`) into an `xyz` file, then make this `xyz` file into a `csv` file. Before continuing to the next file (`wc2.1_5m_prec_02.tif`) however, I want to delete the *original* `tif` file, since it's obsolete. I figured I'd drop the data frame it was stored in. Even when I did, the file won't delete unless I totally leave Stata and delete it like that. Anything I'm missing here? Note, I'm allowed to delete the xyz file just fine. It's the tif files that seem to be problematic here.

Comment: I don't see any problem with `os.remove(file)`. It should delete the `.tif` file.

Comment: I agree. It's not like I'm "using" the csv file for anything yet, or even the tif file, I'm just trying to get rid of it since it's not needed.

Comment: Could you try it with `del ds` or `ds = None` before the `os.remove(file)`?

Comment: Are you executing the python script from within Stata? Stata could execute the script in a way that does not have permission to delete files. I do not know if this is the case but I have given up trying executing python scripts from within Stata as I run in to too many issues. Can you test with a simpler files that only deletes a mock file you create manually? Otherwise delete the files from Stata once the python part is done

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to `del ds`, as had been mentioned above, since that was the dataset variable being keyed on.